# Is there a way to ensure all text-align: center text is indeed centered?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to assemble a footer with Bootstrap. For some reason the footer links appear slightly off-center, despite making sure `text-align: center;` is applied. Is there a way ensure all text elements are indeed aligned properly?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <section class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <h1 class="landing">
            Lorem Ipsum
          </h1>
          <h4 class="landing">
            Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
          </h4>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <section class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1.landing {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 400%;
}

h4.landing {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-links li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `UL` has some left padding. Try removing it.

```
.footer-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8mGk/1/